# Implementing LLL algorithm in Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell

I'm implementing the LLL basis reduction algorithm in Haskell. I'm basing my code on the [pseudocode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#LLL_algorithm_pseudocode). Here is what I have so far. Apologies for the code dump; I strongly suspect the issue lies in `lll` but I'm giving everything just in case.

```
import Linear as L

f v x = v `L.dot` x

gram_schmidt b = 
    let aux vs us =
            case vs of
            v:t -> let vus = map (\u -> project u v) us
                       s = foldr (^+^) zero vus
                       u = v ^-^ s in
                   aux t (us++[u])
            [] -> us
    in aux b []

swap :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
swap i j xs =
    let elemI = xs !! i
        elemJ = xs !! j
        left = take i xs
        middle = take (j - i - 1) (drop (i + 1) xs)
        right = drop (j + 1) xs
    in  left ++ [elemJ] ++ middle ++ [elemI] ++ right

update i xs new =
    let left = take (i-1) xs
        right = drop (i) xs
    in left ++ [new] ++ right

sort_vecs vs = map snd (sort (zip (map norm vs) vs))

lll :: Int -> [[Double]] -> Double -> [[Double]]
lll d b delta =
    let b' = gram_schmidt b
        aux :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]] -> Int -> [[Double]]
        aux b b' k =
                if k >= d then
                    b
                else
                    let aux2 :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]] -> Int -> [[Double]]
                        aux2 b b' j =
                            if j < 0 then
                                let mu = (f (b!!k) (b'!!(k-1))) / (f (b'!!(k-1)) (b'!!(k-1))) in
                                if f (b'!!k) (b'!!k) >= (delta-mu^2) * f (b'!!(k-1)) (b'!!(k-1)) then
                                    aux b b' (k+1)
                                else
                                    let bb = swap k (k-1) b
                                        bb' = gram_schmidt bb in
                                    aux bb bb' (max (k-1) 1)
                            else
                                let mu = (f (b!!k) (b'!!j)) / (f (b'!!j) (b'!!j)) in
                                if abs mu > 0.5 then
                                    let bk = b!!k
                                        bj = b!!j
                                        bb = update k b (bk ^-^ (fromIntegral (round mu)) *^ bj)
                                        bb' = gram_schmidt bb in
                                    aux2 bb bb' (j-1)
                                else
                                    aux2 b b' (j-1)
                    in aux2 b b' (k-1)
    in sort_vecs (aux b b' 1)
```

My issue is that it seems to find a basis of a sublattice. In particular, `lll d [[-0.8526334764831849,-3.125000000000004e-2],[-1.2941941738241598,4.419417382415916e-2]] 0.75` returns `[[0.41107277914220997,0.10669417382415924],[-1.2941941738241598,4.419417382415916e-2]]`, a basis for a index-2 sublattice, and with basis which are almost-parallel. I've been staring at this code for ages to no avail (I thought there was an issue with `update` where `(i-1)` should be `(i)` and `(i)` should be `(i+1)` but this caused an infinite loop). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest splitting this up. Nothing is harder to debug than a single giant function tied in a knot. Referential transparency means you can always split out sub-functions and debug them in isolation, because they can't influence each others' state.

Comment: Is `Linear` from the `linear` package?  If so, where's the `Metric` instance for `[]`?

Comment: @amalloy Thank you, I will give this a try.

Comment: @Carl I'm still rather new so I'm not sure what a Metric instance is, but I haven't had any trouble using any of Linear's methods for lists of Doubles. Is there a modification I should make regarding Linear/[] that might help?

Comment: @zjs Oh, I think I was looking at docs for a really old version of `linear` where that instance didn't exist. Downside to following google links to hackage....